# Youtube api set a dimension

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I tried to set 3d dimension flag in Videos.insert and Videos.update query. But the flag doesn't change. 
Update query example:

Request:

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
{
 "id": "g8X8zeL0uEQ",
 "contentDetails": {
  "dimension": "3d"
 }
}
```

Response:

```
200
- SHOW HEADERS -
{

 "kind": "youtube#video",
 "etag": "\"0Fu6lI6VPLdRMlQU3wwNcowdAUs/fSl6VDWHqWRlQ_1QhmdiESxxFiY\"",
 "id": "g8X8zeL0uEQ",
 "contentDetails": {
  "duration": "PT7S",
  "dimension": "2d",
  "definition": "hd",
  "caption": "false",
  "licensedContent": false,
  "projection": "rectangular"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contentDetails.dimension` to set dimensions flag for videos. It indicates whether the video is available in 3D or in 2D. The contentDetails object contains information about the video content, including the length of the video and an indication of whether captions are available for the video. But [`insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) and [`update`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update) query are not able to set 3D flag.

```
"contentDetails": {
"duration": string,
"dimension": string,
"definition": string,
"caption": string,
"licensedContent": boolean,
"regionRestriction": {
"allowed": [
string
],
"blocked": [
string
]
},
```